# Local Magento 2 broke after switching CSS rendering from server to client

Tags: magento2.3.3

I moved my Magento 2.3.3 instance from server to local. I used git to pull in the server, and ran composer install to get the magento files.

Everything worked well, until I went into admin and changes css rendering from server to client.
After that, I get the following error on the client side

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: template
```

and the admin doesn't have any css applied. The logs are full of Undefined variable" and "main.INFO: Broken reference".

I tried clearing and deleting the cache using cache:clean and cace:flush, I deployed the static content, and rebuilt the indexes. Nothing seems to be working.
I can still access the admin panel, but can't make any changes, and again, there's no css being applied.

Thanks